# ember-cli ember new ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

Fresh install on a Xubuntu desktop VM, fully updated, running `ember new` gets me this:

```
jrusso@ember:~$ ember new jossdo
version: 0.0.37
installing
  create .bowerrc
  create .jshintrc
  create Brocfile.js
  ...
  create tests/test-helper.js
  create tests/unit/.gitkeep
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installing packages for tooling via npm...
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/jrusso/jossdo/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/leek/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/lib/async.js'
    at Error (native)
```

Here are versions of the software I'm using

```
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ bower --version
1.3.5
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ nvm --version
0.7.0
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ npm --version
1.4.9
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ node --version
v0.11.13
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ phantomjs --version
1.9.7
jrusso@ember:~/jossdo$ uname -a
Linux ember 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tried `npm cache clear` in home prior to `ember new` and got the same result.  I had 0.0.35 working but I wanted to do a clean install of 0.0.37 so I cloned my virtualbox snapshot prior to installing any node software, followed the ember-cli gh-pages install procedure and this is what I got.  Relatively new to ember.js, node and linux webdev so please go easy on me.

### UPDATE

Not sure what the issue is here, but after trying a few subsequent `ember new` commands, it does seem to be working.  My first subsequent run completed npm installs and bower installs though it had a few messages for me:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
make: Entering directory `/home/jrusso/testrun/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/jrusso/testrun/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
```

Didn't run `ember serve` on that, but I `rm -rf testrun` and then ran `ember new testrun` again and this time I *didn't* get the `npm ERR!` messages but I still got the `make` messages.

Removed it again and tried `ember new testrun --verbose` and it appears that the NPM errors are sporadic and non-descriptive (the message doesn't contain any indication of which `package.json` it's unable to parse).  I'll continue to update if I have any more issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ha!

Just finished resolving the same issue.

Luckily I saw "you have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements...".

Ran:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Drop the sudo for user-level only.

I'd also updated npm.

Furthermore, I grabbed the latest Xcode command line tools.

Ran the command again for ember-cli global install. This time no issues. Tested to create a new site - all good.

Stef has some further tips for updating an ember-cli project [here](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/).